# What should I be using jQuery(function() OR $(function() in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am confused what should I be using and what is the best practice.

I have seen people using `jQuery(function(){`. Whereas, I was using `$(function(){` uptill now.

So, I want to know **what** should I be using and **why**?

*Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jQuery(function(){` or `$(function(){`. `$` is just a shortcut of `jQuery`. `jQuery` is specifically used where some other JS framework uses the `$` shortcut.

You can also create your own shortcut very easily. The `noConflict()` method returns a reference to jQuery, that you can save in a variable, for later use. Here is an example:
Example:

```
var jq = $.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function(){
    jq("button").click(function(){
        jq("p").text("jQuery is still working!");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using more than one library which uses $ as access specifier, it is suggested to use jQuery. $ is a shortcut and widely used.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what you use since `$` is a synonym for `jQuery`